# What security feature do i use to make my CF application secured?

Tags: security, coldfusion

I have an application built in CF 9. As this was developed way long time back, I am trying to implement some security features now. I only have the knowledge of using **cfqueryparam** to protect the sql injection which i have already implemented in the application code.
But what else do I use to make my application more secure?
I am using ColdFusion 9 and Oracle database.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: You can use CFADMIN secuirty feature in Admin page.

Comment: Did you search before posting? Because it is hard to believe a brief search on ColdFusion security did not turn any results..

Answer (score 6):

It's a very broad question. But i will give you links that will get you started:

1. First you need [check Administering Security](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff2.html)
2. Then check [securing application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e34.html)
3. Then you need to learn how to [lockdown server](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/91025512-cf9-lockdownguide-wp-ue.pdf)
4. As you mentioned, you need to use cfqueryparam in cfquery
5. Also you need to use [best practices](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/DevelopmentBestPractices.cfm) while developing application.

I guess this will make your application very secure.

Comment: Hmm. That looks quite promising statements. The "best practices" is the one I was looking for. Rest, i believe, already applied by the original developer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Vasu, The article 'best practices' gets updated as development trend changes. You might want to go back to it from time to time.

Comment: Ya. sometimes we forget the need of going to the basics. Got your point.

Comment: Server Lockdown guide should be #1 on that list.

Answer (score 5):

here is the developer security guide to make your CF applications secured. you can download this [ColdFusion Developer Security Guide](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ColdFusion+Developer+Security+Guide).
This contains all the basics of security enhancement.

Comment: Thanks Keshav. I should have already hunt the Adobe site for the query. But the link you have given is of extensive help. I'll surely go through the entire pdf. But can you quickly suggest any tips to secure the dB malfunction other than cfqueryparam? Or cfqueryparam is enough to get rid of this?

Comment: @Vasu you should go through the PDF and check the points tushar mentioned in his answer. I think these points are really important for securing any application.